# Discord oauth2 with Firebase functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, discord, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement Discord authentication in my React app, using Firebase. I stumbled upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992730/how-would-i-authorize-users-using-discord-oauth2-0-for-firebase-authentication-o) which suggests calling a Firebase function which redirects to the Discord auth flow (where you need to click 'Authorize').

I'd like for this to behave the same as the Firebase sign in with Google flow. So like this:

1. user clicks a button that says 'Sign in with Discord'
2. a popup opens where Discord asks to Authorize
3. user authorizes by clicking the button on the popup
4. the popup closes and the user is now logged in

How can I trigger a Firebase function (probably a HTTPS function?) from my React app, so it will open a popup? I've tried Firebase's HttpsCallable in the frontend to trigger a Firebase function that calls response.redirect(discordAuthRedirectLink), but this only triggers the function (it doesn't open a popup or redirect).

Comment: You can't open a popup in the client directly from the server, but your Cloud Function can return a value that the client then interprets and opens a popup in response. If that is what you tried and couldn't get to work, please edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the clear answer! I'll try to implement it like this: 1: user clicks login button on React app. 2: button handler in React opens the discord auth link in a popup window. 3: user authorizes using the popup. 4: authorization in the popup triggers the callback url, redirecting back to the React app with a code. 5: call a Cloud Function that will fetch Discord user info using the code (and create a new user if necessary), and return a Firebase auth token. 6: use this Firebase auth token to call Firebase's signInWithCustomToken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open a popup in the client directly from the server (that would be a major security concern), but your Cloud Function can return a value that your client-side code then interprets and opens a popup in response.

Having to perform multiple calls (to multiple services) during a sign-in flow such as this is quite common, so I wouldn't worry too much about that early on.